# Iterable using yield or __next__()

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am looking at making iterable objects and am wondering which of these two options would be the more pythonic/better way, is there no difference or have I got wrong idea about using yield? To me using yield seems cleaner and apparently it is faster than using __next__() but i'm not sure.

```
class iterable_class():

    def __init__(self, n):
        self.i = 0
        self.n = n

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        if self.i < self.n:
            i = self.i
            self.i += 1
            return i
        else:
            raise StopIteration()
```

Using yield:

```
class iterable_class_with_generator():

    def __init__(self, n):
        self.i = 0
        self.n = n

    def __iter__(self):
        while self.i < self.n:
            yield self.i
            self.i += 1
```

Comment: One significant difference: `iterable_class.__iter__` returns the *same* iterator (namely, itself) each time it is called, while `iterable_class_with_generator.__iter__` returns a new, *independent* iterator each time.

Comment: @chepner: Except that the generator is saving its state in instance variables, so calling `__iter__` repeatedly returns distinct but still conflicting iterators.

Comment: True, they are distinct but not-so independent.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One observable difference is that the first version implements an *iterator* (an object that has `__next__` and whose `__iter__` returns itself), while the second one implements an *iterable* (an object that can implements `__iter__` to create some iterator). In most cases this doesn't make a difference because the `for` statement and all itertools accept any iterable.

The difference is visible with the following code:

```
>>> x = iterable_class(10)
>>> next(x)
0
>>> next(x)
1
>>> list(x)
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Obviously this won't work with `iterable_class_with_generator` because it doesn't implement `__next__`. But there is a deeper difference: since `list(x)` accepts any iterable, it would first call `x.__iter__()`, which would in case of `iterable_class_with_generator` create a new generator which would start the count from the beginning. A true generator-based iterator is presented at the end of the answer, but in most cases the difference won't matter.

Regarding the style difference of whether to use a generator or define your own `__next__`, both will be recognized as correct Python, so you should choose the one that reads better to the person or team who will maintain the code. Since the generator version is shorter and generators are a well-understood Python idiom, I'd choose that one.

Note that if you implement `__iter__` with a generator, you don't need to keep iteration state in instance vars because the generator does it for you. The code is then even simpler:

```
class iterable_class_with_generator:
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.n = n

    def __iter__(self):
        for i in range(self.n):
            yield i
```

---

Finally, here is a version of `iterable_class_with_generator` that implements a true iterator that uses a generator internally:

```
class iterable_class_with_generator:
    def __init__(self, n):
        self._gen = self._generate(n)

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        return next(self._gen)

    def _generate(self, n):
        for i in range(n):
            yield i
```

Comment: if i am not wrong in python 2.7 range itself returns list , so it will occupy the memory once it getting called, so how using yield efficient

Comment: @Roushan: The tags say 3.x.

Comment: @Roushan The question is tagged with `python-3.x`, so I used the Python 3 semantics. (Also, Python 3 was released ten years ago.)

Comment: xrange should use in py  2.7 as it returns generator

Comment: @Roushan: xrange returns a lazy sequence object, not a generator. Also, the tags still say 3.x.

Comment: its ok, just cautious to know the same implemenattion in 2.7 :)

Comment: Although the question clearly is about 3.x, these tips about 2.x are valuable because many people are still stuck with 2.x.

Answer (score 2):

The devil is in the details.

chepner already mentioned the significant difference in the comments.

> `iterable_class.__iter__` returns the same iterator (namely, itself) each time it is called, while `iterable_class_with_generator.__iter__` returns a new, independent iterator each time.

This can give you surprising results if you are not aware of exactly what's happening.

```
>>> x = iterable_class_with_generator(5)
>>> it = iter(x)
>>> list(it)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> x.i = 0
>>> list(it)
[]
>>> 
>>> x = iterable_class(5)
>>> it = iter(x)
>>> list(it)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> x.i = 0
>>> list(it)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

As you can see, the generator created from calling `iter` with an instance of `iterable_class_with_generator` stays exhausted once it raises `StopIteration`.

The iterator from an instance of `iterable_class` is that instance itself, so fiddling with `x.i` can change the state of the iterator.

Conclusion:

If you want an iterator, implement `__iter__` (which does nothing but `return self`) and `__next__`. If you want an iterable that is not an iterator itself, implement `__iter__` and return an iterator in the body of this method.

Both approaches are different, and when you wanted an iterable that is not an iterator, the subtle difference can bite you.

Comment: The matter of taste (and external requirements) referred to whether to use a generator or implement an explicit `__next__`. The difference between iterator and iterable is _not_ a matter of taste, but it's also something the OP was likely unaware of.

Comment: @user4815162342 fair enough, I'll reword that part.

Comment: Thanks, and I've made it more explicit in my answer what the readability/taste refers to.